# Make custom post type that is rendered by plugin not queryable

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-post-type

I'm using the `WooCommerce` plugin and with it comes the `products` post type.

For my site, I've created actual `pages` for my products, so I don't need `/products` to exist.

Usually, if I had created the post type, I would add `publicly_queryable'  => false` to make sure the `/products` url didn't exist, but this post type is created by `WooCommerce` so unsure how to go about it? Or if it has any implications.

Trying to remove these unnecessary pages from the sitemap.

Comment: What plugin you use for sitemap ?

Comment: @Orbital - Yoast SEO

Answer (score 0):

So this answer came from [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49251/modify-built-in-post-type-properties) over at the WordPress Stack Exchange site.

Add this to your theme's functions.php file and give it a try. I tested it on a clean WP install with just WooCommerce installed, and it seems to work as intended.

```
function change_wp_object() {
    if(post_type_exists('product')){
        $object = get_post_type_object('product');
        $object->publicly_queryable = false;
    }
}

add_action('init','change_wp_object');
```

I added a check to see if the 'product' post type exists (please note that your question says the post type is called 'products' but it is actually 'product'). Adding that if/condition helps eliminate errors thrown if WooCommerce wasn't installed or activated.

Comment: Hi Joe, so before I implemented this code and went to `/product/product_name`, it would show me the `variations` and other details for the product. Now, after I added in the above code and went to `/product/product_name/`, the page still loaded, but it didn't showcase the `variations` and other details (just showed header and footer). I'm sure you know, I'm trying to remove `/products` from being accessed completely (so `/products/product_name` isn't showing up in the sitemap and accessible on the site)

Comment: So I don't really know much about WooCommerce specifically, my answer above just changes the 'publicly_queryable" setting on the product post type to be false. Before implementing, i went to [my-local-site]/?post-type=product and it listed the products in my install. After implementing the code, it showed no products. In the WP documentation for publicly_queryable in the register_post_type() function, that's one of the examples of what that setting being true does. I couldn't say if there's negative effects inside WooCommerce to setting that to false.

Comment: Also, if I go to [my-local-site]/shop/ I see no products when code is implemented, and when not implemented, it lists my products. I'm guessing /products/ is your "Shop Page" in WooCommerce's settings? As far as the Shop Page goes, that appears to be perfectly fine if you just delete the page, but there are some things in WooCommerce that reference that page, so there may be links in alert messages or generated emails that you'll need to address as well if you're doing away with the Shop Page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude post_type from Yoast SEO sitemap - try this code

```
function sitemap_exclude_post_type( $excluded, $post_type ) {
    return $post_type === 'product';
}

add_filter( 'wpseo_sitemap_exclude_post_type', 'sitemap_exclude_post_type', 10, 2 );
```